# How to access a directory on local computer to upload to s3 using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, cloud, devops

I am fairly new at terraform and wanted to know if there is a way for terraform to access a directory stored in local computer (for example in the Downloads folder) to be used to upload to s3?

If not what would be the best way to go about it. I would appreciate any help on this.

Thank you

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_object

Answer (score 2):

Terraform provides `path.root` which will get the root path to the script. You can combine your path to the root path & upload the file.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "object" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.b1.id # bucket
  key    = "profile"
  acl    = "private"  # or can be "public-read"
  source = "${abspath(path.root)/../Downloads}" # ubuntu
  etag   = filemd5("myfiles/yourfile.txt")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This might seem like a silly question but I have an error with the file path "A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name"

Comment: ```resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "object" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.terraform_bucket.id
  key    = "key-name"
  source = "${abspath(path.root)/Users/username/Downloads}"
  etag = filemd5("Users/username/Downloads/file-name.zip")
}```

Comment: The problem with terraform is that it can identify its own path & `path.root` give the path from where terraform is running. So if you terraform script is also at `Downloads/Terraform` then your path would be `${abspath(path.root)/../file-name.zip`

Comment: If its at `Users/username/Terraform` then your path would be `${abspath(path.root)/../Downloads/file-name.zip  `

Comment: Thank you. I was writing the path to file wrong, it has worked now

Comment: @user16007126 If the answer works, it should be accepted.